# Show recently-deleted posts instead of deleted recent-posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Currently the "deleted recent answers" and "deleted recent questions" page [only show deleted posts that have been **created** in the past 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244144/159916).

If a post which had been created over 60 days ago gets deleted, it will not show up under the "deleted recent answers" and "deleted recent questions" page. This makes finding these recently deleted answers *impossible*.

Case in point: I've [a question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5797650/632951) deleted 3 days ago, and the link can no longer be found (aside from browser history). It doesn't show up in the "deleted recent answers" page, nor does it show up in the "Activity → all actions" page.

Can the functionality of "deleted recent post" be changed to "recently deleted post"?

(Since a post which has been deleted 60 days ago requires that deleted post to have been created 60 days ago, the functionality of "recently-deleted post" remains a strict superset of "deleted recent-post".)

Comment: I never noticed that this feature worked like that... I wonder why it works this way in the first place? Is there some reason for it or is this just a bug? In my opinion this should obviously return recently deleted question regardless of when they were created...

Comment: True, the FAQ even states that ["posts deleted in the last 60 days"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5222/65) are shown. had edited it to better reflect the actual functionality.

Comment: So, this *is* intentional, but I'm not entirely sure why. There's also obviously a lot of support regarding changing it. I'll tag this [tag:status-review] while I work on figuring this out.

Comment: two days and still no one has an answer?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco AFAIK the intent was always to make deletion as discreet as possible so that people wouldn't complain when their old posts (which they weren't monitoring actively) were deleted. You can't track the deletion of your posts (except recent ones which you might still be monitoring actively anyway) unless you maintain a list outside the site. (I thought http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1+whining would turn this up, but he must have used a different word that time.)

Comment: @Gilles He used it in a comment, which search doesn't include. [It would lead to unbelievable amounts of whining. –  Jeff Atwood♦ May 3 '11 at 11:10](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted#comment222981_53297)

Comment: I think that deleted posts should be visible in this list no matter when they were created or deleted. I don't see any reason why I shouldn't be allowed to see a complete list of my own posts that got deleted. If some people wouldn't like this feature, there could be a setting like for example a checkbox saying something like "don't show posts older than 60 days".

Answer (score 4):

Since December 2021 users have been able to see all of their deleted questions and answers on their respective pages. The announcement was made [on MSE in an answer to a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/284336).

> We've been slowly moving towards completing this request over the years and have made incremental improvements to allow users to see content of their own that was deleted. The **TL;DR here is that we have updated (as of 2022-01-12) the recently deleted questions/answers pages to show all deleted questions and answers.**
>
> Additional changes:
>
> - The word "recently" has been removed from all references to these pages, including URLs.
> - The pages now show all of your deleted questions or answers. Paging included, when necessary.
> - These pages can now be referenced by `/users/deleted-answers/current` and `/users/deleted-questions/current` (which will load the pages for the currently logged-in user).
> - The [*Deleted Answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current) page has gotten a major facelift, and is now showing post summaries that are much more inline with our design framework than the old list (it is using a Stacks [`post-summary`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/), including answer score, question title, tags, last action date, and answer excerpt).

That said, this specific ask was completed prior to that, in February of 2020, when [we made the exact change recommended in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/change-no-deleted-recent-answers-questions-to-no-recently-deleted-answers-que).