# Are users notified of deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I realize that [questions *posted* (not *deleted*) more than 60 days ago that are deleted simply vanish into thin air](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306576/show-recently-deleted-posts-instead-of-deleted-recent-posts). I think I asked a question in the beginning of March that is nowhere to be found. (in case you're curious, it was about a replacement for the deprecated [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), but one that works similarly to it giving me the ASCII value - something that KeyboardEvent.key and KeyboardEvent.code don't do).

I received no notification concerning it (except for some downvotes when I posted it, hence I think Community might have deleted it). If I'm not seeing it in my questions nor in my deleted questions, does it mean that it got deleted without any notification?

As an aside, I think this is bad practice, my question had comments and upvotes besides the downvotes. [I already upvoted this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). I guess my only option now is to ask the same question again, doubling the ammount of moderation...?

Comment: It's not gone, you can view your own deleted questions, as well as >10k rep users and mods.

Comment: Here's the link to your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49278648

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thank you! I clicked before on deleted questions and nothing was shown! Could this be a bug?

Comment: I tried this link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/4621141 , is it the wrong link?

Comment: Not exactly a bug, since it has always been this way. Take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327259 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336920

Comment: Thanks! But wow, Machavity is right, it's not obvious *at all*. I thought I couldn't read all my deleted answers and questions